# Split string into two parts on first delimiter occurrence

Tags: kotlin

I have an input string:

```
"aws_acm_certificate_validation"
```

What would be the best way to get a pair of strings separated on the first `_` delimiter occurrence?

```
"aws" to "acm_certificate_validation"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.split()` accepts a limit argument so that:

`"aws_acm_certificate_validation".split("_", limit = 2)`

will give you `["aws, "acm_certificate_validation"]`